# Simstudy package duplicate keys error and variables referenced not previously defined error

Tags: simulate

I tried running the following code and encountered several errors with the simstudy package.

```
library(simstudy)
clusterDef <- defData(varname = "u_3", dist = "normal", formula = 0, 
                   variance = 25.77, id="clus") #cluster-level random effect
clusterDef <- defData(clusterDef, varname = "error", dist = "normal", formula = 0, 
                   variance = 38.35) #error termeriod 
clusterDef <- defData(clusterDef, varname = "ind", dist = "nonrandom",   
                   formula = 25) #individuals per cluster

#Generate individual-level random effect and treatment variable 
indDef <- defDataAdd(varname = "u_2", dist = "normal", formula = 0,
                     variance = 120.62)

#Generate clusters of data
set.seed(12345)

cohortsw <- genData(3, clusterDef)
cohortswTm <- addPeriods(cohortsw, nPeriods = 6, idvars = "clus", perName = "period")
cohortswTm <- trtStepWedge(cohortswTm, "clus", nWaves = 3, lenWaves = 1, startPer = 1, grpName = "trt")
cohortswTm <- genCluster(cohortswTm, cLevelVar = "clus", numIndsVar = "ind", level1ID = "id")
```

> Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin ||
>   !anyDuplicated(f__,  :    Join results in 2700 rows; more than 468 =
>   nrow(x)+nrow(i). Check for duplicate key values in i each of which
>   join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try
>   by=.EACHI to run j for each group to avoid the large allocation. If
>   you are sure you wish to proceed, rerun with allow.cartesian=TRUE.
>   Otherwise, please search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki,
>   Stack Overflow and data.table issue tracker for advice.

```
cohortswTm <- addColumns(indDef, cohortswTm)

#Define coefficients for time as a categorical variable 
timecoeff1 <- -5.42
timecoeff2 <- -5.72
timecoeff3 <- -7.03
timecoeff4 <- -6.13
timecoeff5 <- -9.13

#Generate outcome y 
y <- defDataAdd(varname = "Y", formula = "17.87 + 5.0*trt + timecoeff1*I(period == 1) + timecoeff2*I(period == 2) + timecoeff3*I(period == 3) + timecoeff4*I(period == 4) + timecoeff5*I(period == 5) + u_3 + u_2 + error", dist = "normal")

#Add outcome to dataset
cohortswTm <- addColumns(y, cohortswTm)
```

> Error: Variable(s) referenced not previously defined: timecoeff1,
>   timecoeff2, timecoeff3, timecoeff4, timecoeff5

Does anybody know why I am getting the errors that were highlighted above? How would I fix the code to prevent them from occuring?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The first error is generated because you are trying to create individual level data within each cluster, but each cluster appears repeatedly (over 6 periods). genCluster is expecting that `cLevelVar` is a unique id. In this case, you can generate 6 individuals per cluster per time period by modifying the `genCluster` command to be

```
cohortswTm <- genCluster(cohortswTm, cLevelVar = "timeID", 
      numIndsVar = "ind", level1ID = "id")
```

This code creates a "closed" cohort, individuals are observed only in a single period. Generating an open cohort, where individuals might be observed over time as well, is a bit more involved, and is described [here](https://www.rdatagen.net/post/analyzing-the-open-cohort-stepped-wedge-trial-with-binary-outcomes/).

The second error is generated because simstudy data definitions can only include variables that have been defined in the context of the data definition. So, any constants need to be in the formula. (The formula itself can be updated using updateDef and updateDefAdd if you want to explore the effects of different covariate levels.)

This is how y should be defined:

```
y <- defDataAdd(varname = "Y", formula = "17.87 + 5.0*trt - 
    5.42*I(period == 1) - 5.72*I(period == 2) - 7.03*I(period == 3) -
    6.13*I(period == 4) - 9.13*I(period == 5) + u_3 + u_2 + error", 
    dist = "normal")
```

Comment: Thank you Dr. Goldfeld. Conceptually, I would like to highlight that the updates to the code lead to the creation of an open cohort stepped-wedge design wherein new individuals are recruited once per period and only a single measurement is taken on them during the study. The link that you provided produces a closed cohort...wherein the same individuals are recruited at baseline and followed through time. I do wonder how it would be possible to recreate that same cohort in the link without the Markov processes that were presented. Would this be possible?

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up. I am not sure that definitions are universal at this point, since these ideas are relatively new, but this [paper][1] has a nice clear delineation. The closed cohort follows the same individuals over the entire study. The open cohort follows people for shorter periods within the study period. And the traditional conception of the stepped-wedge measures individuals only once - this is a cross-sectional design. So, I think my blog post does fall under the open cohort design.


  [1]: https://trialsjournal.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13063-015-0842-7

Comment: You could certainly create an open (or closed cohort) without a Markov process - I used that because I wanted to create a scenario that allowed health status to change over time independent of what was going on in in the intervention.

Comment: With tweaks, I think I created the closed cohort dataset that I want with your post: https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-simulation-for-power-analysis-an-example-based-on-a-stepped-wedge-study-design/. But, when I fit the lme model I get this error: 

Error in solve.default(estimates[dimE[1] - (p:1), dimE[2] - (p:1), drop = FALSE]) :    system is computationally singular.

I tried dropping the covariates separately (period, intervention) and it works, but I know I need both. There is no perfect correlation between all of the covariates and the response...so I assume the matrix is invertible?

Comment: You may need to send me the code - it is hard for me to know what is going on ...